# MySQL get MAX value with COUNT for every row in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Suppose, I have a table

```
           pages_urls
+----+---------+---------------+
| id | site_id | download_date |
+----+---------+---------------+
|  1 |       1 | 2012-01-01    |
|  2 |       1 | 2012-12-31    |
|  3 |       2 | 2012-01-01    |
|  4 |       2 | 2012-12-31    |
+----+---------+---------------+
```

For every site_id I want to select:

1. The last download date
2. Number of records in the table for this site

I tried this query:

```
SELECT
    pages_urls.site_id,
    max_table.download_date,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    pages_urls
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT
    site_id,
    MAX(download_date) AS download_date
FROM
    pages_urls AS max_pages_urls
WHERE
    max_pages_urls.site_id=site_id
) AS max_table
ON
    pages_urls.site_id=max_table.site_id
GROUP BY
    site_id;
```

But I got this instead of the desired result:

```
            desired result           ║            my query result         
+---------+---------------+----------║---------+---------------+----------+
| site_id | download_date | COUNT(*) ║ site_id | download_date | COUNT(*) |
+---------+---------------+----------║---------+---------------+----------+
|       1 | 2012-12-31    |        2 ║       1 | 2012-12-31    |        2 |
|       2 | 2012-12-31    |        2 ║       2 | NULL          |        2 |
+---------+---------------+----------║---------+---------------+----------+
                                     ║
```

[fiddle with table and query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78587/1)

How can get the necessary information?

Comment: Problem is probably the fact that your subquery does not have a `group by`.  Anyway, JuergenD's answer eliminates the subquery :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT site_id, MAX(download_date) AS download_date, count(*)
FROM pages_urls
GROUP BY site_id;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78587/2)

Comment: I need to do something extremely similar to this...I need to select `MAX(column)` with a `GROUP BY`, and I also need a `count(*)`, except I need `count(*)` for the *whole table*, not just what's matched by the `GROUP BY`. Is it possible to do this without using a subquery and doing `select count(*) from subquery`? Or would a subquery be fine, even for large data sets, if i just need the `count`? (Basically, if all I need is the `count`, does the MySQL server still execute the whole subquery and then count the results, or is it smarter than that?)